# Small modification to the limit of a textarea characters counter

Tags: javascript

The code below counts the chars typed in a textarea. If you reach the 250 limit you can not add more. How can I let people to type more than 250?

Like ok, you have 250 minimum but it doesn't mind if you put more than this. Thanks!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var maxLength=250;
function charLimit(el) {
    if (el.value.length > maxLength) return false;
    return true;
}
function characterCount(el) {
    var charCount = document.getElementById('charCount');
    if (el.value.length > maxLength) el.value = el.value.substring(0,maxLength);
    if (charCount) charCount.innerHTML = maxLength - el.value.length;
    return true;
}
</script>

<form>
    <textarea onKeyPress="return charLimit(this)" onKeyUp="return characterCount(this)"  rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>
<p><strong><span id="charCount">250</span></strong> more characters available.</p>
```

Comment: change the value of maxLength? I think I'm missing the point

Comment: why are you posting dupes of basically the same Q over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow the number of characters entered to exceed the `maxLength`, the following blocks of code should be removed.

```
function charLimit(el) {
    if (el.value.length > maxLength) return false;
    return true;
}
```

and

```
if (el.value.length > maxLength) el.value = el.value.substring(0,maxLength);
```

and

```
onKeyPress="return charLimit(this)"
```

You might also want to consider modifying the following line to prevent displaying negative numbers.

```
if (charCount) charCount.innerHTML = Math.max(maxLength - el.value.length, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
var maxLength=250;
```

change it to whatever max you want

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for the reply but I think I didn't explain well what I want. I need a chars available counter but I don't want the script to delete all chars that exceeded the 250 limit. It's like you have a minimum of 250 not only 250.

Comment: You write on that textarea with a limit of 250 chars. If you try and write more than 250 for example with a right click paste, the script will keep only the first 250 chars and delete from the textarea any other. My purpose is to keep the counting but not set a limit. A user may add more than 250 chars but only the first 250 chars are counted. After this is appeared as 0.

Answer (score 0):

the maxLength is beeing restricted by a var named "maxLength"

If you change that value you can change the max value required, because of all that comprobations that you're making

Comment: You write on that textarea with a limit of 250 chars. If you try and write more than 250 for example with a right click paste, the script will keep only the first 250 chars and delete from the textarea any other. My purpose is to keep the counting but not set a limit. A user may add more than 250 chars but only the first 250 chars are counted. After this is appeared as 0.